# Excel VBA: Copying/pasting a row given a workbook reference

Tags: excel, vba

This is driving me CRAZY.

I have a workbook/sheet that I refer to via xlWBk.Sheets(1)

I want to basically do the following:

```
xlWBk.Sheets(1).The sixth row.Copy Everything (text, format, etc)
xlWBk.Sheets(1).Arbitrary row.Paste Everything (text, format, etc)
```

Is there a quick/clean way to do this? I've tried so many combinations of row/range paste commands and it's not pasting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
xlWBk.Sheets(1).Range("A6").EntireRow.Copy xlWBk.Sheets(1).Range("A7")
```

This'll copy the entire row of 6 to row 7.

**Edit**

Thanks nutsch, i forgot to quantify the paste book/sheet in the answer. great catch!. Code above updated.

Comment: Unfortunately this still did not work properly -- the paste row is still blank

Comment: Still not working :( The row where things are to be pasted is just completely blank, and there is indeed data in the 6th row to copy

Comment: Try `xlWBk.Sheets(1).Range("A6").EntireRow.Copy xlWBk.Sheets(1).Range("A7")`

Comment: @Gimp, you want to bear on this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150118/edit-other-users-answer-or-give-your-own-answer#comment432208_150118?

Comment: i chimed in and upvoted your question, and another answer. I appreciated you comment and feedback to the answer. I actually immediately went to edit my code and saw that other random users had rejected your change.